# Difficulty printing each iteration of a transposition sorting algorithm

Tags: c, sorting, printf

I'm following "C by Dissection" as I'm new, and I am attempting to print out each iteration of a transposition sorting algorithm with the expected result being:

```
   Unordered: 7 3 66 3 -5 22 -77 2
After pass 1: -77 7 66 3 3 22 -5 2    
After pass 2: -77 -5 66 7 3 22 3 2    
...    
     Ordered: -77 -5 2 3 3 7 22 66
```

However I can only get as far as  printing out:

```
   Unordered: 7 3 66 3 -5 22 -77 2
After pass 1:
After pass 2:
...
     Ordered: -77 -5 2 3 3 7 22 66
```

And thus I'm missing the main point of the exercise. I've attempted placing a printf("%d", a[i]); in numerous places but it doesn't give the desired result, so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int *p, int *q);
void transposition (int a[], int n);

#define SIZE 8

int main (void)
{
   int arr[SIZE] = {7, 3, 66, 3, -5, 22, -77, 2};
   int i;

   printf("   Unordered: ");
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }

   transposition(arr, SIZE);


   printf("\n     Ordered: ");
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}

void swap (int *p, int *q)
{
   int tmp;

   tmp = *p;
   *p = *q;
   *q = tmp;
}

void transposition (int a[], int n)
{
   int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
         if (a[i] > a[j]) {
            swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
         }
      }
      printf("\nAfter pass %d: ", i);

   }
}
```

Comment: I recommend calling your sorting function `sort` or `sort_by_transposition` or `transposition_sort` rather than just `transposition`; the name `transposition` makes it sound like the function is applying one transposition, whereas it's actually sorting the array by applying up to n^2 transpositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print sequence, you have to add statements to print sequence.

```
void transposition (int a[], int n)
{
   int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
         if (a[i] > a[j]) {
            swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
         }
      }
      printf("\nAfter pass %d: ", i);

      /* add this */
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
         printf("%d ", a[j]);
      }

   }
}
```

Points to change from the code in `main()`

```
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
```

are:

- Change `i` to `j` because `i` is used in the outer loop.
- Change `arr` to `a` according to the argument.
- Change `SIZE` to `n` according to the argument.

Comment: This answer is recommending copypasting `for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {  printf("%d ", a[j]);  }` every place where printing the array is desired. But wouldn't it be **much** better to move that code to a function `print_array`?

Comment: @Stef You can write an answer suggesting that.

Comment: Also, you forgot `printf("\n");`.

Comment: @Stef I didn't. Newline is in `printf("\nAfter pass %d: ", i);`

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid duplicated code by encapsulating useful code into a function

Since printing the array is something that you need to do more than once, you should write a function that does that:

```c
void print_array(int arr[], int n, char const *title)
{
   printf("\n     %s: ", title);
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

### Using our function `print_array`

Then you can call that function whenever you want to print the array:

- Once before sorting, titled "Unordered";
- Once after sorting, title "Ordered";
- At every iteration of the `for`-loops, with a title specifying the value of `i`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int *p, int *q);
void sort_by_transpositions (int a[], int n);
void print_array (int a[], int n, char const *title);

#define SIZE 8

int main (void)
{
   int arr[SIZE] = {7, 3, 66, 3, -5, 22, -77, 2};
   int i;

   print_array(arr, SIZE, "Unordered");

   sort_by_transpositions(arr, SIZE);

   print_array(arr, SIZE, "Ordered");

   return 0;
}

void swap (int *p, int *q)
{
   int tmp;

   tmp = *p;
   *p = *q;
   *q = tmp;
}

# define BUFFERSIZE 100

void sort_by_transpositions (int a[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   char after_pass_i_title[BUFFERSIZE];

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
         if (a[i] > a[j]) {
            swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
         }
      }
      snprintf(after_pass_i_title, BUFFERSIZE, "After pass %d", i);
      print_array(a, n, after_pass_i_title);
   }
}
```

Note use of function `snprintf` from header `stdio.h` which is similar to `printf` but prints to a string instead of printing to stdout.

### Allowing the user to choose whether they want the sort to be silent or verbose

Maybe the user wants to sort the array, but do not want to receive tons of lines of output as a consequence of sorting. You could add a parameter to your sorting function, specifying whether or not to do all the printing:

```c
void sort_by_transpositions (int a[], int n, int verbose)
{
   int i, j;
   char after_pass_i_title[BUFFERSIZE];

   if (verbose)
      print_array(arr, SIZE, "Unordered");

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
      {
         if (a[i] > a[j])
         {
            swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
         }
      }
      if (verbose)
      {
          snprintf(after_pass_i_title, BUFFERSIZE, "After pass %d", i);
          print_array(a, n, after_pass_i_title);
      }
   }

   if (verbose)
      print_array(arr, SIZE, "Ordered");
}
```

Then you can call your function from `main` and specify verbose (`1`) or not verbose (`0`):

```c
# define VERBOSE 1
# define SILENT  0

int main (void)
{
   int arr[SIZE] = {7, 3, 66, 3, -5, 22, -77, 2};
   int i;

   sort_by_transpositions(arr, SIZE, VERBOSE);

   return 0;
}
```

Note that I moved all calls to `print_array` to inside function `sort_by_transpositions` rather than having some calls inside `sort_by_transpositions` and some other inside `main`. It's easier if all the printing statements are located inside the same function rather than disseminated all over the place.